# How to work on a new theme in wordpress without downtime

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to install a new theme and work on it, not activating it unitl the website is done. What is the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are re-theming a production site, i would pull it down and do all my work on a local environment, then once its complete, push it up to a staging server to test. Once you have done a thorough QA on the staging environment, then push all the changed up to production.